# Problema con imágenes en Django

Tags: django, imagen, django-models, django-urls, django-views

Tengo un problema al intentar subir imágenes a django ya que en lugar de la imagen, me muestra unos signos como esto ->�PNG  IHDR00W�� cHRMz&�����u0�`:� que me ocupan toda la pantalla. El programa intenta mostrar desde la siguiente vista la imagen

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from .models import Equipos_ligas

# Create your views here.

def prueba(request):
   partido = Equipos_ligas.objects.get(name_id='RealMadrid')
   return HttpResponse(partido.imagen)
```

Equipos_ligas es un modelo que esta en el modulo models de la propia app:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Equipos_ligas(models.Model):
     name_id = models.CharField(max_length=60)
     name_vista = models.CharField(max_length=60)
     liga = models.CharField(max_length=60)
     imagen = models.ImageField(null=True)
```

Se añade a settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Las urls de las app y del proyecto principal son respectivamente:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns=[
    path('prueba/', views.prueba),
    ]


urlpatterns +=  static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

```
"""casino URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from casino.Ervast import liga, premier
from django.conf import settings
from futbol import urls
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('probame/', include('futbol.urls')),
    ]
```

y se han hecho las correspondientes migraciones, pero el resultado son esos caracteres extraños, alguien sabe donde esta el fallo?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que HttpResponse espera una cadena o un iterador, lo que ves es el contenido binario de la imagen.

Si quieres mostrar una imagen tienes varias opciones, la más sencilla es que crees un template y ahí rendericé la imagen.

Necesitas crear un template en html donde se mostrará la imagen:

Modificas tu vista para mandar el objeto partido y mostrar la imagen guardada:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def prueba(request):
   partido = Equipos_ligas.objects.get(name_id='RealMadrid')
   return render(request, "mi_template.html", {"partido": partido})
```

Ahora, si lo que quieres es que se descargue el archivo tienes que indicar que es un archivo adjunto en la cabecera del HttpResponse junto con el contenttype, seria algo asi:

```
def prueba(request):
   partido = Equipos_ligas.objects.get(name_id='RealMadrid')
   response = HttpResponse(partido.imagen, headers={'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg','Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="mi_imagen.jpeg"'})
```